# Dumping xml file into a mysql table is only inserting 1 row

Tags: mysql, xml

I am trying to load the above file into a mysql table and it is only loading the first row, instead all of the row. I used the following SQL query statement LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE 'file_path'
-> INTO TABLE table_name
-> ROWS IDENTIFIED BY `'<users>'`;

So after the query it return the following message: Query OK, 1 row affected (4.28 sec)
Records: 1  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 0

What could be the issue? I have been on these for days now. I really need your assistance on this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<users>
  <row Id="-1" Reputation="1" CreationDate="2011-03-02T19:40:57.283" DisplayName="Community" LastAccessDate="2011-03-02T19:40:57.283" WebsiteUrl="https://meta.stackexchange.com/" Location="on the server farm" AboutMe="&lt;p&gt;Hi, I'm not really a person.&lt;/p&gt;&#xA;&lt;p&gt;I'm a background process that helps keep this site clean!&lt;/p&gt;&#xA;&lt;p&gt;I do things like&lt;/p&gt;&#xA;&lt;ul&gt;&#xA;&lt;li&gt;Randomly poke old unanswered questions every hour so they get some attention&lt;/li&gt;&#xA;&lt;li&gt;Own community questions and answers so nobody gets unnecessary reputation from them&lt;/li&gt;&#xA;&lt;li&gt;Own downvotes on spam/evil posts that get permanently deleted&lt;/li&gt;&#xA;&lt;li&gt;Own suggested edits from anonymous users&lt;/li&gt;&#xA;&lt;li&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006&quot;&gt;Remove abandoned questions&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/li&gt;&#xA;&lt;/ul&gt;&#xA;" Views="176" UpVotes="2959" DownVotes="96864" AccountId="-1" />
  <row Id="2" Reputation="101" CreationDate="2011-03-02T20:09:07.117" DisplayName="Geoff Dalgas" LastAccessDate="2015-04-23T19:30:02.537" WebsiteUrl="http://stackoverflow.com" Location="Corvallis, OR" AboutMe="&lt;p&gt;Dev #2 who helped create Stack Overflow currently working at Microsoft. I love all people willing to share their knowledge. Without community we are nothing.&lt;/p&gt;&#xA;&lt;p&gt;Find me on:&lt;/p&gt;&#xA;&lt;p&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;http://www.twitter.com/SuperDalgas&quot; rel=&quot;nofollow noreferrer&quot;&gt;Twitter&lt;/a&gt;&#xA;&lt;br&gt;&lt;br&gt;&#xA;&lt;a href=&quot;http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/welcome-stack-overflow-valued-associate-00003/&quot;&gt;Stack Overflow Valued Associate #00003&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&#xA;" Views="66" UpVotes="2" DownVotes="0" AccountId="2" />
  <row Id="3" Reputation="101" CreationDate="2011-03-02T20:35:27.447" DisplayName="Emmett" LastAccessDate="2016-10-31T23:03:35.570" WebsiteUrl="http://minesweeperonline.com" Location="San Francisco, CA" AboutMe="&lt;p&gt;co-founder of &lt;a href=&quot;https://airtable.com&quot; rel=&quot;nofollow noreferrer&quot;&gt;Airtable&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&#xA;&#xA;&lt;p&gt;formerly a dev at Stack Overflow :)&lt;/p&gt;&#xA;" Views="40" UpVotes="2" DownVotes="0" AccountId="1998" />
  <row Id="4" Reputation="101" CreationDate="2011-03-02T20:40:09.953" DisplayName="David Fullerton" LastAccessDate="2019-11-15T06:00:32.087" Location="Melbourne, FL, USA" AboutMe="&lt;p&gt;Officially voted &lt;a href=&quot;https://twitter.com/df07/status/504677877544390656&quot; rel=&quot;nofollow noreferrer&quot;&gt;World's Okayest Boss&lt;/a&gt; by a plurality of coworkers in 2014.&lt;/p&gt;&#xA;&#xA;&lt;p&gt;Formerly:&lt;/p&gt;&#xA;&#xA;&lt;ul&gt;&#xA;&lt;li&gt;CTO / VP Eng at Stack Overflow&lt;/li&gt;&#xA;&lt;li&gt;New York (Careers &amp;amp; Area 51) lead&lt;/li&gt;&#xA;&lt;li&gt;Stack Exchange 1.0 dev lead&lt;/li&gt;&#xA;&lt;li&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;http://www.fogcreek.com/&quot; rel=&quot;nofollow noreferrer&quot;&gt;Fog Creek Software&lt;/a&gt; developer and &lt;a href=&quot;http://www.fogcreek.com/jobs/summerintern/&quot; rel=&quot;nofollow noreferrer&quot;&gt;intern&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/li&gt;&#xA;&lt;/ul&gt;&#xA;" Views="31" UpVotes="0" DownVotes="0" AccountId="32917" />
  <row Id="5" Reputation="1068" CreationDate="2011-03-02T20:45:08.207" DisplayName="Greg" LastAccessDate="2023-08-13T23:41:23.480" WebsiteUrl="https://ReflectiveCode.com" Location="United States" AboutMe="&lt;p&gt;Good code works.&lt;br /&gt;&#xA;Better code is elegant.&lt;br /&gt;&#xA;Best code is maintainable.&lt;/p&gt;&#xA;" Views="72" UpVotes="98" DownVotes="0" AccountId="7455" />
  <row Id="8" Reputation="101" CreationDate="2011-03-02T20:45:40.877" DisplayName="Ben" LastAccessDate="2011-04-02T14:59:25.280" WebsiteUrl="http://www.benstanfield.com/" Location="Washington, DC" AboutMe="I'm the Data Center Czar for a large government science institute in Bethesda, MD." Views="13" UpVotes="0" DownVotes="0" AccountId="487511" />
  <row Id="9" Reputation="101" CreationDate="2011-03-02T20:45:57.787" DisplayName="Nick Craver" LastAccessDate="2017-03-02T03:51:55.567" WebsiteUrl="https://nickcraver.com/blog/" Location="Winston-Salem, NC" AboutMe="&lt;p&gt;I am a Principal Software Engineer at Microsoft working on Azure Functions and related hosting technologies. Formerly the Architecture Lead for Stack Overflow where my day job consisted of being a Developer, Site Reliability Engineer, and DBA.&lt;/p&gt;&#xA;&lt;p&gt;I design and build very fast things in hopes of making life easier for millions of developers.&lt;/p&gt;&#xA;&lt;p&gt;Blog: &lt;a href=&quot;https://nickcraver.com/blog/&quot; rel=&quot;nofollow noreferrer&quot;&gt;nickcraver.com/blog&lt;/a&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&#xA;Twitter: &lt;a href=&quot;https://twitter.com/Nick_Craver&quot; rel=&quot;nofollow noreferrer&quot;&gt;@Nick_Craver&lt;/a&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&#xA;My Developer Story: &lt;a href=&quot;https://stackoverflow.com/story/ncraver&quot;&gt;stackoverflow.com/story/ncraver&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&#xA;&lt;p&gt;&lt;sub&gt;Disclaimer: I have &lt;em&gt;no idea&lt;/em&gt; what I'm talking about, all my answers are guesses!&lt;/sub&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&#xA;" Views="17" UpVotes="0" DownVotes="0" AccountId="7598" />
  <row Id="10" Reputation="2149" CreationDate="2011-03-02T20:45:59.987" DisplayName="ack" LastAccessDate="2022-06-10T15:04:28.130" Location="California" AboutMe="" Views="54" UpVotes="15" DownVotes="2" AccountId="15513" />

</users>
```

Comment: Is this the entire file? If yes, rowcount=1 is correct, since there is only one <users>.

Comment: Yes you are right but that is not what i want to do. The mistake is from me . I wanted using the row tag as my row and due to lack of understanding of what xm is and how it is structured I used the user tag. Check the below answer were I outline what I did wrong and how I correct it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

After some reading on xml file from google, I got to understand the structure of xml file. With the understanding comes the realisation I was supposed to used the "row" tag instead of the "users" tag.
You see, when I used this line ROWS IDENTIFIED BY `'<users>'`; I am targeting the user tag as the row, this will make the query to look for the closing tag of the user tag and it is at the end of the file `</users>`.

So the right thing to do is to target the row tag and that is how i was able to solve this problem.

So, I correct my SQL query statement from:
LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE 'file_path' -> INTO TABLE table_name -> ROWS IDENTIFIED BY `'<users>'`;
, to:
LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE 'file_path' -> INTO TABLE table_name -> ROWS IDENTIFIED BY `'<row>'`;